# How to merge rows into a single long row with same values using php for loop

Tags: php, laravel

I want to merge the rows of my table using for loop with if else statement inside. However, I am having a hard time figuring out the exact logic to be used in order for it to work. The problem is that there is 20 rows with one same value. All I need is 1 row with the same value ex.(NAME = colspan 25) so that it will be just one.

I tried all the knowledge I know but failed. I am still new in the for loop with if else inside.

Is it possible to use for loop and if else? For loop for counting the data and if else for comparing iterations from one another. I thought that when u compare iteration and it is not the same it will stpo and it will be used for the colspan. (But i dont know the logic behind it)( I mean executing the logic I just said)

```
<tr>  <!-- Sales Group -->
                @foreach ($br as $branch)
                <?php 
                $zone_desc = App\Zone::getZoneDesc($branch->zonecd);
                $msg_desc = App\MsgRef::getMsgDesc($branch->msg);
                $no_br = count($br);
                $total_alloc =0 ;
                $c_br = 0;
                $brchs = $brchs.$branch->branch_code.','; 
                $count_walloc = 0; 
                $desc= ($msg_desc->msg_desc);
                $flag = 0;
                $count = count($msg_desc);
                //dd($msg_desc);

                ?>


                    @for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)

                        <?php

                        // $nextIndex = $i + 1;
                        // $currentIteration = array($i);
                        // $nextIteration = array($nextIndex);


                            if($desc == $msg_desc->msg_desc ){
                                $count = $flag + 1;

                    ?>
                            <td height="20" colspan = "$count" style="font-size: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 42px; max-width: 42px;" class="{{$branch->branch_code}}">{{$msg_desc->msg_desc}}</td>   

                <?php   
                             }else{
                            $count = $flag + 1; 

                         ?> 

                            <td height="20" colspan="$count" style="font-size: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 42px; max-width: 42px;" class="{{$branch->branch_code}}">{{"$msg_desc->msg_desc"}}</td>  

                         <?php
                             }
                         ?>

                    @endfor

            @endforeach 




                @for($c = $no_br; $c< 25; $c++)
                <td height="20" style="min-width: 42px; max-width: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
                @endfor     
                <!-- <td></td>
                <td></td> -->

            </tr>
```

[This is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70iWZ.png)

Comment: Change your query and get the data using `group by`, and for each group create a single row and show the related data in that row using loop and colspan

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Is there a simplier way? Using for loop and if else? The person I was working with said that I cannot change other stuffs.